# dvide 2 column ina table on each other

Tags: sql

I have a factor table and it has two columns: `totalprice` and `paidprice`.

I want divide the count of total price on paidprice and *100 and i want return result as percentage.

```
select  TotalPrice/PaidPrice as h
from Factors 
where TotalPrice>=PaidPrice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT (COUNT(PAID_PRICE) / CAST(Total_Price AS FLOAT)) * 100 AS Result
from #Table 
WHERE TOTAL_PRICE >= PAID_PRICE
GROUP by TOTAL_PRICE
```

http://rextester.com/PKXSYV97387

Comment: select count(TotalPrice) *100 / COUNT(paidprice)
from Factors 
where TotalPrice>=PaidPrice                                                                                            I want answer of it in decimal ---- I have 4 factor 3 customers paid their factor but 1 of them didn't paid now I want answer of 75%

Answer (score 0):

TABLE:

```
**PAID_PRICE**     **TOTAL_PRICE**
35                        50
40                        45
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT (SUM(PAID_PRICE)/SUM(TOTAL_PRICE))*100
FROM TABLE_NAME WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE TOTAL_PRICE>=TOTAL_PRICE
```

Try this?

Comment: may you include and example of your table and the query you have tried?

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
    cast(
        SUM(CASE WHEN PaidPrice>=TotalPrice THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 
        100 /
        COUNT(FactorID)as varchar(5)
    ) + '%' as percentageOFcomepletfactor
from 
    Factors
```